# How to add product to customer cart in magento2 programmatically

Tags: magento2, customer, addtocart

Everything works well, but it adds for all by default, but I need it added for a specific customer, regardless of whether it’s active at the moment or not, I have a customer ID, but how can i add  product to his card ?

```
    ...
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository,

    ...
    $this->_cart = $cart;
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->_quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;

    ...

public function autoAddToCart(){

  ....

try {
    $data = [
        'qty' => $products_count,
        'product' => $products_id,
        'bundle_option' => $selectionProds
         ];
     $this->_cart->addProduct($_product,$data);
     $this->_cart->save();
     $cartId = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getId();
     $quote = $this->_quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
     $this->_quoteRepository->save($quote);
     $quote->collectTotals();
      }
      catch(\Exception $e) {
           echo  $e->getMessage();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to assign customer to quote

```
$quote->assignCustomer($customer);
```

more info you can found
https://webkul.com/blog/create-quote-and-order-programmatically-in-magento2/

hope it will help you